# Convert datatype of column while filtering records using DataView.RowFilter

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, datatable

I have a datatable with a column having **Date**. Dates are stored as

> 2018/11/14 @ 12:10 PM.
>
> 2018/11/15 @ 13:49 PM.
>
> 2018/11/16 @ 15:37 PM. 
>   and so on

Now I have to filter records on the basis of date only.

I am filtering records using below code but it is not returning correct data.

```
dv.RowFilter = "SUBSTRING(DateColumn,1,10)>='2018/11/01' AND SUBSTRING(DateColumn,1,10)<='201811/30'";
```

I tried to cast substring value as we do in Sql

```
(cast(DateColumn as date))
```

but it throws error.

Can anyone help me how I can get date part from that column and change it's data type to date.

Comment: You have a typo `201811/30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you can use for `RowFilter`s is described on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2#expression-syntax).

In order to convert the value in a given column to a date you need to use the `CONVERT` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2#functions), rather than `cast`.

```
(cast(DateColumn as date))
```

Would become:

```
CONVERT(DateColumn, 'System.DateTime')
```

Unfortunately I'd be surprised if the format of your string is one that will readily convert to a `DateTime` (though trying surely won't hurt on the off chance that it does!), something like this may give you some success though:

```
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(DateColumn, 1, 10), 'System.DateTime')
```

To which you can then apply your filter and say:

```
dv.RowFilter = "CONVERT(SUBSTRING(DateColumn, 1, 10), 'System.DateTime') >= '2018/11/01'";
```