# C# DataFilter cannot find column System.Data.Evaluate.Exception

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, dataview

I'm exporting an excel sheet to a Data Table dt.

Then I have this code for setting up a Date format:

```
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MMM-dd";
culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

My filter string is the following:

```
string strFilter = "CONVERT([Creation date], 'System.DateTime') <= '2021-02-23' AND CONVERT([Creation date], 'System.DateTime') >= '2020-12-01'";
```

Then I'm executing a method for creating a filtered data view.

```
public DataTable filterDataTable(DataTable dt, string filter) {
                
                DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                dv.RowFilter = filter;
                DataTable dt2 = dv.ToTable();
                
                return dt2;
                }
```

Upon execution of above I get an exception of type  System.Data.Evaluate.Exception and Message: "Cannot find column [OK]." Hresult: -2146232032.

In the source excel file the column name I want to filter is "Creation date", this column is recognized in Excel as General format. Example values in the column: 2020-12-29 14:05:33, 2020-07-03 13:05:19.

How can I filter this Data View using date conditions?

---

EDIT - solution

Before filtering, I created a new column "Creation_date" of DateTime type and added parsed values from the old column.

```
public DataTable getDtWithDateType(DataTable dt) 
    {
        
        dt.Columns.Add("Creation_date", typeof(DateTime));
        
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                row["Creation_date"] = DateTime.ParseExact(row["Creation date"].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);   
                            }

        return dt;
        }
```

Once I had that extended DataTable I was able to implement the Linq solution proposed by Svetoslav Angelov.

Comment: I'm working on a solution created by a previous employee. Also, as far as I know there was some issue with CopyToDataTable() method.

Answer (score 1):

This is the the way i use with Linq simple and efficient

```
public DataTable FilterDataTable(DataTable dt, DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate, int columnIndex)
        {
            DataTable output = dt.Clone();
            var filterMenuRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(
                r => r.Field<DateTime>(columnIndex) >= minDate
                && r.Field<DateTime>(columnIndex) <= maxDate);
            if (filterMenuRows != null && filterMenuRows.Any())
            {
                output = filterMenuRows.CopyToDataTable();
            }

            return output;
        }
```

if you want to filter other type of data columns you shuld use RowFilter or Select such as

```
public DataTable FilterDataTable(DataTable dt, string filter, string columnName)
        {
            DataTable output = dt.Select(columnName +"='" + filter + "'"); 
            
            return output;
        }
```

Assuming you use iteration when you fill the DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ADDRESS", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("NOTE", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("BIRTH_DATE", typeof(DateTime));
            
            //excel is not zero based!!
            int maxExcelRows = 20001;
            int maxExcelColumns = 5;
            DataRow nextRow = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 1; i <= maxExcelRows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= maxExcelColumns; j++)
                {
                    //new line
                    if (j == 1)
                    {
                        nextRow = dt.NewRow();
                    }

                    //write the values
                    if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value != null)
                    {
                        if (j == 5) // your DateTime column here
                        {
                            // NOTE: use the exact format of the outer document
                            nextRow[j - 1] = DateTime.ParseExact(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString(), "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            nextRow[j - 1] = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString();
                        }
                    } 
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(nextRow);
            }
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use strings as DateTime ... i strongly suggest you parse the data to DateTime on import from excel so then you will have no problems with it.

Comment: Code compiles but it does not return a filtered data table. My column values in Excel are in a yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format but the expected System.Date format is dd.MM.yyyy or dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm. I'm sure that "Creation date" column has a string type in the dt exported from Excel.

Comment: Oh, and I should've mentioned that my data table is quite large - around 20k records.

Comment: The format on the sheet dose not matter ... as soon as you import it to the C# memory as DataTable the code to filter should work no matter the format (it is a object type). My guess is you did not hit the proper column index OR you`r column in the DataTable is not type of DateTime. Try to debug with some breakpoints if you can specify some data such as 3-4 rows i can try to check it.

Comment: I'm 100% positive I set a correct column index. Yes, column is certianly not of DateTime type, it's String. So part of the problem is converting that column to DateTime somehow. I couldn't have created a new datatable and parsing for each row because it would take too long because DataTable is large.

Comment: using System.Globalization;
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/21 10:56:09", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: How to apply it to a DataTable or DataView? Will it work without a row iteration?

Comment: I will try to explain the whole procedure in the answer above

Comment: I now see what you mean - setting a format before exporting to DataTable. Unfortunately, I have to use an already existing method ExportToTable() (I will not have access to even viewing this method or modifing it) so I cannot implement your proposed solution at this stage. This is why I was asking about what to do with a Data View (based on an already filled Data Table).

Comment: I saw a post with an example of a field conversion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612037/convert-datatype-of-column-while-filtering-records-using-dataview-rowfilter) but it failed in my case and I don't know why. I posted the exception message above and it seems odd.  I think there might also be an issue with the date formats - that System.DateTime format (dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm) is different from the format in the "Creation date" field (yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss).

Comment: When you use you`r method just add another DateTime column at the end and iterate all rows to fill it with the correct object type. As my first comment was.. it is not recommended to use strings as DateTime

Comment: I will post the code I used to create a new DateTime column and parse the old column date. The solution you earlier posted now works although the result is inclusive of the minDate and exclusive of  the maxDate (even though "r.Field<DateTime>(columnIndex) <= maxDate"), no idea why. But I added line "maxDate = maxDate.AddDays(1);" and now it works exactly as expected.

Comment: It is becouse the TimeSpan property in the DateTime object ;) you need to change the min and max TimeSpan of the provided parameters